# How can I set the width of a landscape figure to the textwidth?

Tags: floats, landscape

I would like to have a figure in landscape format to fill the whole page, i.e. I would like the width to be the textheight of a portrait page or the textwidth of a landscape page, respectively.

Here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdflscape}    

\begin{document}    
\begin{landscape}
 \begin{figure}
 \centering
 \def\svgwidth{\textwidth}
 \input{figure.pdf_tex}
 \caption{Example Figure}
 \end{figure}
\end{landscape}    
\end{document}
```

When running this through pdfLaTeX I get a landscape figure that is as wide as the textwidth of a portrait page.

Using

```
\def\svgwidth{\textheight}
```

does not change the output.

How can I get the figure to fill the whole page?

---

I cannot include figure.pdf since this format is not allowed to upload, but you can find figure.png further down.

The following is the code content of figure.pdf_tex:

```
\begingroup% 
 \makeatletter%
 \providecommand\color[2][]{%
 \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the 
package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
        \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
 }%
 \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
 \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
   \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}% 
 }%
 \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
\ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
\setlength{\unitlength}{782.075bp}%
 \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
  \relax%
 \else%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
 \fi%
 \else%
\setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
 \fi%
 \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
 \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
 \makeatother%
 \begin{picture}(1,0.48489595)%
  \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{figure.pdf}}%
  \put(0.21413974,0.24055332){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)
[lb]{\smash{Text}}}%
\end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

[image: figure]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the contents of the file `figure.pdf_tex`. I think this will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to distort the figure? If it has scaled as much as possible re. width then forcing it to scale to height will obviously distort the proportions of the image.

Comment: Try \linewidth.  It works for me with \resizebox.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: \linewidth works perfectly for me. Please post this as an answer.

Comment: @cfr: I do not want to distort the figure. Thing is, it has not scaled as much as possible regarding width.

Comment: @IanThompson: I am not sure how to do this: [link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/how-to-provide-pdf-tex-files-for-mwes).

Comment: There is an 'edit' at the bottom left of your question. Click that and add the contents of `figure.pdf_tex` as code to your question so that people have everything they need to reproduce the problem. I'm not sure if this answers the question as I'm not certain what you are unsure how to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `\linewidth`. It works for me with `\resizebox`.